# Legal aspect of iframes to embed third party content

Tags: html, iframe, stumbleupon

My question is about copyrights, and using third party content in a monetized web page. How would services like stumbleupon embed other webpages using iframes to their website, and make an income of them? Is there any legal aspect to this?

In other words, simply, is there any sentence a website needs to insert into their TOS or such disclaimers before embedding third party content to prevent any legal issues?

Thank you.

Comment: Is there a solicitors.stackexchange.com?

Comment: See http://bit.ly/1cjAPeC No idea, not my downvote. I guess because it's off topic.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about legal advice.

Answer (score 3):

I haven't been able to find the website, but I don't think it's illegal, as long as you don't claim it's your own content or overuse it. I fact, you could do better by stating that the content is take from the link.

You may want to read the following:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copyright_aspects_of_hyperlinking_and_framing

Comment: thank you...actually i posted it here only after visiting that wikipedia link..it doesn't give me much details..but thanks...